# What's the deal with the "speculative" tag (on the main site)?

Tags: discussion, tags

The ['speculative' tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/speculative/info) says not to use that tag. Huh? Why even have it then? There's only one question with the tag:

[Will Google Android ever support .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214615/will-google-android-ever-support-net)

and while that's a popular question, I don't see how it necessitates such a weird tag situation.

Comment: It's a locked post, only moderators would be able to remove it from that question.

Comment: Can we just delete that question. The answer to that question (or any on the same quilt) is "maybe if someone that can do it cares enough to do it".

Comment: @yellowantphil: I was trying to add that tag to a question of mine, saw the description box, and changed my mind.

Comment: Thanks Jon! http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/214615/5

Comment: Looks like it was popular around 2009/10 for a few questions that were deleted years ago  and wouldn't remotely be on topic for SO these days.